# Sass function to take a value from a class

Tags: sass

I I have the following classes:

- h-10
- h-100
- h-170
- h-380

Is it possible to have a sass function that will see the 'h-' and then grab the value and then do something?

I'm hoping to add heights to a container. Our CMS (AEM) will let me write out classes based on a drop down value.

Answer (score 2):

I think `str-slice($string, $start-at, [$end-at])` should do what you're looking for.  Something like this:

```
/* Pass in your classes */
@mixin containerHeights($classes) {
    /* Loop over each one */
    @each $class in $classes {
        /* Grab everything starting at the 3rd character
        $height: str-slice($class, 3);

        /* build your classes from the list */
        .#{$class} {
            height: #{$height}px;
        }
    }
}
```

Now you should be able to use your mixin like this:

`@include containerHeights(h-10 h-100 h-170 h-380);`

The compiled result will look like:

```
.h-10 {
    height: 10px;
}
.h-100 {
    height: 100px;
}
.h-170 {
    height: 170px;
}
.h-380 {
    height: 380px;
}
```

Comment: Be careful about converting numbers to strings. You should rather use `$height * 1px` instead. [Here is a well-explained post about it](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sass-units/)

Comment: Thanks James, I started something like this, and this confirms it.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [list](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#lists) and an [each directive](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#each-directive).

```sass
$sizes: 10, 100, 170, 380;

@each $size in $sizes {
  .h-#{$size} {
    height: ($size * 1px);
  }
}
```

---

**Output**

```css
.h-10 {
  height: 10px;
}

.h-100 {
  height: 100px;
}

.h-170 {
  height: 170px;
}

.h-380 {
  height: 380px;
}
```